# How to retrieve size of a data type?

Tags: c++

Let `a` be an array. So what is the difference between `a.size()` and `sizeof(a)`?

Comment: how exactly is a declared and of what type?

Comment: All the answer to this question are guesswork. You need to provide more information. Perhaps a small code example.

Answer (score 3):

`.size()` can return anything, depends on how it is implemented.

Anyway, `.size()` **usually** returns the size of an **container**, in other words - the number of elements, that the container contains.

The `sizeof` operator is integrated operator, that returns the number of bytes, allocated on the stack. For example

```
        char a[50];
        char* b = new char[50];
        cout << sizeof( a ) << '\n';
        cout << sizeof( b );
```

prints 50 (which is `50  * sizeof( char ) = 50 * 1 = 50` ), and the second line prints 8 - as this is the size of the pointer (**my machine is x64**, that's why it's 8, if I had 32bit CPU, it would be 4).

`cout << sizeof( *b );` would print 1, as `*b` dereferences the pointer and returns the first element of the array (it's the same as `sizeof( b[0] )` which is `sizeof( char )` )

In other words, you'd better rely on `.size()` if you want to see the number of elements, if it's a container and if it provides such method, of course.

---

Other example:

```
class A
{
        int a;
        char b[100];
};

class B
{
        int a;
        char* b;
public:
        B()
        {
                b = new char[100];
        }
        ~B()
        {
                delete[] b;
        }
};
int main()
{
        cout << sizeof( A ) << '\n';
        cout << sizeof( B ) << '\n';
        B b;
        cout << sizeof( b ) << '\n';
        return 0;
}
```

The first one, on a x64 plarform, will print 104, as we have `100*sizeof(char) + sizeof(int) (=4 )` (**note** `104 mod 8 == 0`, you'll see why );

The second one and the third one will print the same. **But note**, we have alignment here! On x64, the alignment is on 8B, so `sizeof( char * )` gives 8, `sizeof( int )` gives 4 and this makes 12. **BUT** `12 mod 8 == 4` which is != 0, so because of the alignment, `sizeof( B )` prints **16** ( 16 mod 8 == 0 ).

So, when you use `sizeof`, be very careful..
Hope that helps (:

---

For your question about list, take a look at this:

```
        list< int > lint;
        list< char > lchar;
        cout << sizeof( lint ) << '\n';
        cout << lint.size() << '\n';
        cout << sizeof( lchar ) << '\n';
        lint.push_back( 10 );
        lint.push_back( 10 );
        cout << lint.size() << '\n';
        cout << sizeof( lint ) << '\n';
```

All operators `sizeof` will print the same, depends on the implementation of `std::list`. But the first `.size()` will return 0, as there're no elements, and the second one will return 2, as we have 2 elements in the list.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(a)` is the number of bytes used by `a`, not including any dynamically allocated memory. This is a compile time constant. You can also use it with types, `sizeof(int)` gives you the number of bytes in an int.

`a.size()` is usually defined for container types, and gives the number of elements currently in the container (not the number of bytes). This is a runtime value, that changes as you add or remove objects from the container.

Answer (score 0):

`a.size()` gives you value that is special for class. For example length of a string or a list. It depends on type of a class and person who implemented it. But usually `size` is meaningful like in lists.

Sizeof is an operator that you should avoid if you are a beginner programmer. It was widely used in C to `alloc` memory. It returns how much space your object occupies in memory. In C++ we use `new` to dynamically allocate memory. It is much easier. More about sizeof: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a.size(), but sizeof(a) returns its length **in bytes**. If you want the number of elements in the array, divide it by the size of each element. For example:

```
int size = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(*myArray);
```

Comment: but i think the data type of both is size_t

Comment: To nitpick: it is the size in units of `char` elements. That is, if `CHAR_BIT` is 16, then `sizeof(uint32_t)` will be 2.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is an array -

```
int a[5] ; // Taking it as an array that can hold integers.
```

Now -

```
a.size(); // Error. `a` is not a class type to use `.` operator on it. 

sizeof(a); // Correct. It returns 20 because 5*4 bytes.
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` is a unary operator that returns the size of the **datatype**, in number of bytes.

```
sizeof(std::array<int, 3>) == sizeof(int[3]) == 3 * sizeof(int)
class Foo
{
  int a, b;
};
sizeof(Foo) == sizeof(int) * 2
```

`size()` is a method of `template<typename T, size_t S> std::array<T,S>` returning the **number** of elements in the array.

```
std::array<int, 3> a = {1,2,3};
a.size() == 3;
```